# Separate name string into first and last name

Tags: php

If I use the same name for both the first and last name or use a ' my name splitting function is not working as intended. How can I make it work even if the string looks like:

1. Jeanne D'Arc
2. Lang Lang

The first will return the whole name in the $last_name string and the second one will return only one name in the `$last_name` string.

```
function split_name($name) {
    $name = trim($name);
    $last_name = (strpos($name, ' ') === false) ? '' : preg_replace('#.*\s([\w-]*)$#', '$1', $name);
    $first_name = trim( preg_replace('#'.$last_name.'#', '', $name ) );
    return array($first_name, $last_name);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: huh? Why not just `explode` the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split text string into $first and $last name in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637145/split-text-string-into-first-and-last-name-in-php)

Comment: because I want first and potential middle names and last name separated into two. Is there a way to explode only the last word as last name?

Comment: Sorry, but it is not possible to decide which part of a combined name string is surname, which is family name. The local differences between naming concepts in different cultures of the world makes this impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me! It is assuming that you only have one last name and that it's the last word of the string, but the user will be able to edit this anyway so it's just a starting point. Thank you guys.

```
function split_name($name) {
    $parts = explode(" ", trim($name));
    $num = count($parts);
    if($num > 1)
    {
        $lastname = array_pop($parts);
    }
    else
    {
        $lastname = '';
    }
    $firstname = implode(" ", $parts);
    return array($firstname, $lastname);
}
```

Comment: James Van Der Beek, Leonardo da Vinci, John Smith Jr. Like @arkascha said there are tons of localities that this will not work for.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sergio answer. Take a look what is already possible to do with PHP. explode do the same thing as your split_name.

Source:
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php