# Split strings with full name into just first name

Tags: php, regex

I know this question has been answered in here before, but the different functions suggested in the other questions have not been to any help for me - and I´ve tried some few.

I have for example this string with three names that outputs from my database every time it's being loaded:

```
$string = "Joe Hansen, Carl Clarkson Clinton, Miranda Cobweb Fisher-Caine";
```

I only want it to output:

```
$string = "Joe, Carl, Miranda";
```

I tried this one: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637145/split-text-string-into-first-and-last-name-in-php) - but it only outputs the first name in some situations and not every time. Is there a easy solution to this one? I also tried explode and implode but did not get that to work either.

Comment: have you try anything ?

Comment: `explode()` by comma, `explode()` every exploded item by space, take first item from each

Comment: kerbholz, I tried that as well. The problem I had is that you can't explode an already exploded string since its containing an array?

Comment: What @kerbholz meant was `foreach (explode() by comma) { explode() by space }`

Comment: Nick, I got it. Going to give it a shot. I see this question got downvoted quite fast. Too bad there is so little room to ask questions in here when you have tried different solutions already and don't get it to work. Not really helping people that are new to programming and eager to learn.

Comment: What you should have done to avoid downvoting is posting code you already tried. People probably just assumed you haven't put any effort in solving this.

Comment: kerbholz, I see. I'll post some more examples that I've tried next time. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$string = "Joe Hansen, Carl Clarkson Clinton, Miranda Cobweb Fisher-Caine";

$names = explode(",", $string);
$firstNames = array_map(function($name) {
    $split = explode(" ", trim($name));
    return reset($split);
}, $names);

echo implode(", ", $firstNames);
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Marking your answer as the solution when available since you were the first one.

Answer (score 1):

First you can `explode()` string with comma `,` separated. Then go through the loop.
and get first name in the array with `substr()` and then implode with `,`.

```
$string = "Joe Hansen, Carl Clarkson Clinton, Miranda Cobweb Fisher-Caine";
$names = explode(",", $string);

$firstNames = array();
foreach($names as $name){
    $firstNames[] = substr(trim($name), 0, strpos(trim($name), " "));
}
echo implode(", ", $firstNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

First explode the string on `,`, loop through the array, then push the elements in a new array and implode it.

```
$string = "Joe Hansen, Carl Clarkson Clinton, Miranda Cobweb Fisher-Caine";
$new_string=explode(",",$string);
$slipt_arr=explode(" ",$new_string);
$final_arr=array();

foreach ($new_string as $value)
{
    $elements=array_filter(explode(" ",$value));
    array_push($final_arr,current($elements));
}
echo implode(", ",$final_arr);
```

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful to other users if you explain why they might prefer your approach over the other 4 answers.