# How to split given Google API getName value into first_name and last_name using Laravel and Google API login system?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, google-api, google-oauth

I have created a user table and trying to implement Google API Login system.

My users table has fields for `first_name` and `last_name`, but Google API provides only a getName request, how could I split the given value of getName to two pecies and fill my migration table with given values?

LoginController:

```
    public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }

    $existingUser = User::where('email', $user->getEmail())->first();

    if ($existingUser) {
        auth()->login($existingUser, true);
    } else {

        $newUser                    = new User;
        $newUser->provider_name     = 'google';
        $newUser->provider_id       = $user->getId();
        $newUser->first_name        = $user->getName();
        $newUser->last_name         = $user->getName();
        $newUser->email             = $user->getEmail();
        $newUser->email_verified_at = now();
        $newUser->save();

        auth()->login($newUser, true);
    }

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
}
```

I know there is a way to make it happen with custom Php script and the answer is here [Split text string into $first and $last name in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637145/split-text-string-into-first-and-last-name-in-php/28907177#28907177)

But can't figure out how to implement it with my `LoginController` function `handleProviderCallback`

P.S I would not want to change my `users_table` to have only one column for `name`

Comment: Please keep in mind that by far not every name is "Firstname Lastname". There are names like "Foo de la Bar" and "Lastname Firstname". It's probably close to impossible to do this safely.

Comment: Thanks. I have thought about that, but for example you can catch the first name values like first name, middle name in one column and for the last_name just catch the ending last name

Comment: No, you can _not_ just do that. If you think you can, then for `Foo de la Bar`, explain what you think the _“values like first name, middle name”_ would be here, and _how_ you think you would grab those from that given input.

Comment: So you are saying the only way would be is just to make a one column for name in users_table?

Comment: What do you intend to do with users who dont add a first name and last name or any name actually.

Comment: At least German has last names that are identical to first names, leading to confusion even among humans. A "list of all first names" for example won't do. Yes, just having a "name" column is probably the best solution. Google did this for a very good reason I think.

Comment: Thanks. Made a choice to stick with one column in DB

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "Foo le Da LI";

$str_split = explode(' ',$str);
$first_name = $sec_name = $third_name ='';
for($i =0;$i<count($str_split);$i++){
        $first_name = $str_split[$i];
    if($i==1 && $str_split[$i] != ''){
        $sec_name = $str_split[$i];
    }
    if($i>1 && $str_split[$i] != ''){
        $third_name .= ' '.$str_split[$i];
    }
}

echo " First Name ".$first_name;
echo " second Name ".$sec_name;
echo " Third Name ".$third_name;
```

You can Use php explode method to parse the name. In this scenario if you have one name
it will give you 1st name only if middle name is available then 2nd name and if further it will concatenate to third name. I hope this meets your requirement.